# website creation on iis7 - red cross mark

Tags: windows, iis-7

I have created a site with default setting..just gave a site name, provided physical path to that, with a html file (default.html) but when I am trying to browse this site in the browser, it is not displaying this file and there is red cross mark on the site. pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you solve this issue? Check out [this](http://www.freelists.org/post/exchangelist/Red-Cross-Marks-in-IIS,7) link. I had the same problem and in the end it the red crosses were just cosmetic issues, everything worked fine.